# Creating List From File In Python

Tags: python, list, file

The file contains:

```
1 19 15 36 23 18 39 
2 36 23 4 18 26 9
3 35 6 16 11
```

From that I'd like to extract list as follows:

```
L = [1,19,15,36,23,18,19,2,36........... ect.]
```

What is the most efficient way to do so?

Comment: Are they space/newlines separated?

Answer (score 5):

You can use itertools.chain, splitting each line and mapping to ints:

```
from itertools import chain
with open("in.txt") as f:
    print(list((map(int,chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in f)))))
[1, 19, 15, 36, 23, 18, 39, 2, 36, 23, 4, 18, 26, 9, 3, 35, 6, 16, 11]
```

For python2 use `itertools.imap` instead of map. using chain with map and itertools.chain avoids reading all the file into memory at once which is what `.read` will do.

Some timings for python3 on a file the same as your input * 1000:

```
In [5]: %%timeit
with open("ints.txt","r") as f:
    list(map(int,re.split(r"\s+",f.read())))
   ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 8.55 ms per loop

In [6]: %%timeit                                                
with open("ints.txt","r") as f:
    list((map(int, chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in f))))
   ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 5.76 ms per loop

In [7]: %%timeit
...: with open("ints.txt","r") as f:
...:      [int(i) for i in f.read().split()]
...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 5.82 ms per loop
```

So itertools matches the list comp but uses a lot less memory.

For python2:

```
In [3]: %%timeit                                                
with open("ints.txt","r") as f:
     [int(i) for i in f.read().split()]
   ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 7.79 ms per loop

In [4]: %%timeit                                                
with open("ints.txt","r") as f:
    list(imap(int, chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in f)))
   ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 8.03 ms per loop

In [5]: %%timeit                                                
with open("ints.txt","r") as f:
    list(imap(int,re.split(r"\s+",f.read())))
   ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 10.6 ms per loop
```

The list comp is marginally faster but again uses more memory, if you were going to read all into memory with the read split approach imap is again the fastest:

```
In [6]: %%timeit
   ...: with open("ints.txt","r") as f:
   ...:      list(imap(int, f.read().split()))
   ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 6.85 ms per loop
```

Same for python3 and map:

```
In [4]: %%timeit                                                
with open("ints.txt","r") as f:
     list(map(int,f.read().split()))
   ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 4.41 ms per loop
```

So if speed is all you care about use the `list(map(int,f.read().split()))` or `list(imap(int,f.read().split()))` approach.
If memory is also a concern combine it with chain. Another advantage to the chain approach if memory is a concern is if you are passing the ints to a function or iterating over you can pass the chain object directly so you don't need to keep all the data in memory at all.

One last small optimisation is to map str.split on the file object:

```
In [5]: %%timeit
with open("ints.txt", "r") as f:
    list((map(int, chain.from_iterable(map(str.split, f)))))
   ...: 
100 loops, best of 3: 5.32 ms per loop
```

Answer (score 3):

```
with open('yourfile.txt') as f:
    your_list = f.read().split()
```

To cast it to an integer. You can use a list compregension:

```
your_list = [int(i) for i in f.read().split()]
```

This might result in exception when the value can not be casted.

Comment: BTW: This is approach is good for small and medium sized files.

Comment: @vks The default split splits at spaces and newlines. But I have to test to `\r`...

Comment: In Python 2 and 3: `>>> '1\r\n2'.split()` → `['1', '2']`

Answer (score 2):

```
f=open("output.txt","r")
import re
print map(int,re.split(r"\s+",f.read()))
f.close()
```

You can use `re.split` which will return a list and `map` to `int`.

Answer (score 1):

If you are okay with using `numpy` library ,another method would be to use `np.fromstring()` giving the file's `.read()` as input to it , Example -

```
import numpy as np
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    lst = np.fromstring(f.read(),sep=' ',dtype=int)
```

At the end `lst` would be a numpy array, if you want a python list, use `list(lst)`

`numpy.fromstring()` always returns a 1D array , and when you give space as the separator , it will ignore extra whitespaces, which include newlines.

---

Example/Demo -

```
In [39]: import numpy as np

In [40]: with open('a.txt','r') as f:
   ....:     lst = np.fromstring(f.read(),sep=' ',dtype=int)
   ....:

In [41]: lst
Out[41]:
array([ 1, 19, 15, 36, 23, 18, 39,  2, 36, 23,  4, 18, 26,  9,  3, 35,  6,
       16, 11])

In [42]: list(lst)
Out[42]: [1, 19, 15, 36, 23, 18, 39, 2, 36, 23, 4, 18, 26, 9, 3, 35, 6, 16, 11]
```

---

Performance testing -

```
In [47]: def func1():
   ....:     with open('a.txt','r') as f:
   ....:         lst = np.fromstring(f.read(),sep=' ',dtype=int)
   ....:         return list(lst)
   ....:
In [37]: def func2():
   ....:     with open('a.txt','r') as f:
   ....:         return list((map(int,chain.from_iterable(line.split() for line in f))))
   ....:

In [54]: def func3():
   ....:     with open('a.txt','r') as f:
   ....:         return np.fromstring(f.read(),sep=' ',dtype=int)
   ....:

In [55]: %timeit func3()
10000 loops, best of 3: 183 µs per loop

In [56]: %timeit func1()
10000 loops, best of 3: 194 µs per loop

In [57]: %timeit func2()
10000 loops, best of 3: 212 µs per loop
```

If you are okay with `numpy.ndarray` (which is not that different from list) , that would be faster.

Answer (score 0):

You may use `re.findall`.

```
import re
with open(file) as f:
    print map(int, re.findall(r'\d+', f.read()))
```